# can we implement SPP profile on android device?

Tags: android, bluetooth

How can we achieve or implement the SPP profile for android bluetooth? it's very entry level question but please give me some entry point to start with?

Comment: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth.html seems like a good place to start

Comment: for different profile we need to use different UUID otherwise rest is same for android bluetooth communication

Answer (score 0):

SPP is the only profile that you can reliably use on Android. Use BluetoothSocket and away you go.